# Using android's XML "onClick" property to pass a value to a method

Tags: java, android, android-xml

I have a simple android app that has quite a number of buttons, all doing ever-so-slightly different operations to a number. At present, I have a different method for each function. The  method is called using the XML property "onClick" of the button.

I am trying to add even more buttons, but to save myself time and code, I thought I'd write one method for all buttons. This method should be passed a value telling it about the operation to be done.

I would really like to just be able to give the value that should be passed to that method **in the XML**, rather than having to write it as code using OnClickListener().

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, you are passing a value to the method: the id of the clicked button.

The click handler usually looks like:

```
public void ClickHandler(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case BUTTON_X:
            //do some stuff
        case BUTTON_Y:
            // do some other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. That `v.getId()` will do great.

Answer (score 1):

you can use tag or id of view object in method onClick(View view), and use these as you want to do.